# Trouble with pointer access to std::fstream

Tags: c++, io, c++98

Having not used C++'s i/o facilities for a long while (instead using the C linux API operations), I'm trying to at least familiarize myself with the way C++ proper does things. I'm working under Ubuntu 12.04., in accordance to C++98, using gcc -Wall which compiles with no errors or warnings. The issue came up when I needed to create a new file which I will first write to, then later read from. The issue is as follows:

```
#include <fstream>

std::fstream::openmode o_M = std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out;
std::fstream::openmode o_M1 = o_M | std::fstream::trunc;

std::fstream* preproc;
preproc = new std::fstream(out_Name.c_str(), o_M1); // (1)
if ( !(preproc->good()) )
    errExit(1, "can't open file <%s>", out_Name.c_str());

preproc->put('c');
(*preproc) << "foo";
```

To the best of my understanding, this should write "cfoo" to the file; however, nothing is written, while the file **is created with the proper permissions**. I've gone over many iterations of what might be false (clearing the stream; opening in different modes; explicitly opening the pointed to file first;...), to no avail. Also, earlier in the same project, I create and use an fstream pointer to an **existing** file no problem (using the same syntax, with no openmode qualifiers (I of course tried not using openmodes too for the file above)) - reading from the existing file only though.

When I instead use non-pointer access, as in

```
std::fstream TEST(out_Name.c_str(), o_M1); // (etc, ancillary changes)
```

all works fine.

I am confused. I'm probably not seeing the forest for the trees, and would be grateful for for someone pointing out what I'm missing.

Comment: So you're opening two file streams for input/output on the **same** file name and your wondering why... what? Why using two **buffered** (hint) io streams on the same file give you the results you're seeing?

Comment: The TEST was just added for debugging. My code used the preproc pointer, and I couldn't write to it using either of the above two operators ( <<, put()). @WhozCraig. I don't see though why opening the same file twice should be an issue - this isn't about race conditions or so. If you like, same question with anything TEST related removed.

Comment: If `TEST` shouldn't be there in the first place, it will help significantly if it is removed from the entrails. as it is posted and described, it appears you're expecting writes trough two different open files streams on the same file to maintain a write-sync order of operations. I hope it is clear how it can be seen that way. So the *real* problem is a dynamic-opened `std::fstream` doesn't seem to be writing to your target file, is that correct? `TEST` has nothing to do with this?

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes, and good suggestion. I'll edit the original code to the bottom once home (5 mins). As I hadn't worked with C++ fstreams in such a long while, I checked if it would work if I used non-pointer access; and it did.

Comment: ok. that'd probably be best. I threw together [a simple sample](http://pastebin.com/Mf5wX767) of what I think you're doing, and it seems to work correctly, so not sure what the problem is. The output of the paste bin snippet is `cfoobar` as expected. Anyway, have a safe trip.

Comment: @WhoCraig: that's exactly what I do, and it doesn't work on my machine. (thanks much for writing this up, and see above for changes based on your suggestion - maybe you see a type or so I'm not seeing)

Comment: Maybe the stream's dtor will flush and close which is not called in the pointer version?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: any suggestion what to try?

Comment: @WhozCraig: You figured it out in your code: for some reason, I need to flush() when done writing (while I see how that is logical, it's not in Stroustrup's book who I pulled to compare after I noticed this made it work...). I suggest you post something to the sort as an answer, so i can accept it? I could see how someone else might run into the issue and find this of value.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: actually, your suggestion works too. Would be good if one of you two at least write an answer maybe (in my code, the pointer will be a global deleted much later, so I have to use the flush() route instead, but it works in principle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't `flush`ing, `close`ing or `delete`ing the stream, so the buffer isn't being flushed. Your stack version works because the stream is flushed and closed when the object is destroyed after it falls out of scope.

Either flush the stream, for instance by calling `flush` or `close`, or delete your pointer with `delete preproc;`. Better still don't use objects allocated on the heap if possible.

You could also set your `fstream` to work in unbuffered mode by calling

```
preproc->rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(NULL, 0); // nullptr for C++11
```

immediately after opening the stream, although it's unlikely this is what you want.

If you must use the heap, with C++11 you could take advantage of `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr`. If you are stuck with C++98 there is also `std::auto_ptr` (caveat emptor).

Comment: Yes, thanks; after the discussion above (and what you write) I see now what's going on (I won't be able to use C++11 for this project; and - as long as I don't re-factor my code - I can't use the pointer as it's currently a global).

Comment: @gnometorule In that case either `close` or `flush` the stream.

Comment: +1, including the smart pointer usage, the zero-buffer, etc. All that and a bowel of grits. nice writeup.

Comment: @WhozCraig `bowel of grits` that doesn't sound too appetizing :D